# Difference between $dx \wedge dy$ and $dxdy = dA$.

Tags: differential-forms

(Beginner in differential forms)

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, consider the differential form $\omega = dx \wedge dy$ and infinitesimal area element $dA = dxdy$. I already know that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} w = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} dA.$$ So is $dx \wedge dy$ more of a precise way of writing $dA$ or are they just different entities whose integral happen to be same.

Comment: Are they really equal? The value of the integral on the left depends on the orientation that you’ve chosen for the surface, while the one on the right doesn’t.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term $dx\,dy$ should only occur in nested double integrals. In reality the "area element" dA of elementary calculus refers to Lebesgue measure in ${\mathbb R}^2$. I use to write ${\rm d}A={\rm d}(x,y)$ when necessary. Note that this area element is *unsigned*, meaning that there is no question of orientation or ordering of the variables $x$, $y$. One then has, e.g.,
$$\int_{B(0,1)}{\rm d}(x,y)=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dy\>dx\ .$$
Contrasting this the exterior product $dx\wedge dy$ is *signed*: By convention $x$ is considered as the first variable and $y$ as the second variable, leading to 
$$dx\wedge dy={\rm d}(x,y),\quad dy\wedge dx=-{\rm d}(x,y)\ .$$
 It follows that
$$\int_{B(0,1)} dx\wedge dy=\pi,\quad \int_{B(0,1)} dy\wedge dx=-\pi\ .$$

Comment: So is it right to interpret that both $dA$ and $\omega$ are infinitesimal small area element with the difference being that the former does'nt have information about orientation whereas later has information about the orientation?

Comment: Yes. Note that ${\rm d}A$ transforms with the absolute value of the Jacobian whereas $\omega$ transforms with the exact Jacobian in case of a variable transformation.

Answer (score 1):

In *A Course In Mathematics For Students of Physics* Bamberg & Sternberg refer to objects like $\sigma\,dA$ as *densities*. You can think of $\sigma\,dA$ as representing, say, the electrical charge on a tiny patch of a surface. This quantity doesn’t depend on the orientation of the surface, nor does the *absolute* double integral $\int_R\sigma\,dA$.

By contrast, you can view the two-form $f\,dx\wedge dy$ as representing a flux through that same tiny surface patch. Here, the orientation matters: we need to know which side of the surface is “outside” to be able to say which way the flow is going: the value of the double integral $\int_R f\,dx\wedge dy$ depends on the orientation that you’ve chosen for $R$. With the correct choice of orientation, you can indeed have $\int_R\sigma\,dA=\int_R\sigma\,dx\wedge dy$. Choosing the opposite orientation will change the sign of the integral on the right.

These two types of objects behave differently under pullback. For a two-form, we have $$\alpha^*(f\,dx\wedge dy) = (\alpha^*f)(\det J)\,du\wedge dv,$$ where $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\alpha_2)^T$ and $J$ is the Jacobian matrix $$J=\pmatrix{ {\partial\alpha_1\over\partial u} & {\partial\alpha_1\over\partial v} \\ {\partial\alpha_2\over\partial u} & {\partial\alpha_2\over\partial v} }.$$ When $\alpha$ is orientation-preserving ($\det J\gt0$) and one-to-one, then $\int_R \alpha^*(\tau)=\int_{\alpha(R)}\tau$. On the other hand, the pullback of the density $\sigma\,dx\,dy$ is $$\alpha^*(\sigma\,dx\,dy) = (\alpha^*\sigma)\,|\det J|\,du\,dv.$$ The absolute value of the determinant reflects the fact that we don’t care about orientation and we have $\int_R \alpha^*(\sigma\,dx\,dy)=\int_{\alpha(R)}\sigma\,dx\,dy$ without requiring that $\alpha$ be orientation-preserving as we did for the integral of a two-form.